# Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2 . 
I am getting this exception in console logs. I have tried to search about handled promise rejection but unfortunately no luck.

```
unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./CheckboxComponent class CheckboxComponent - inline template:3:2 caused by: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError {_nativeError: Error: Error in ./CheckboxComponent class CheckboxComponent - inline template:3:2 caused by: Cannot …, originalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_CheckboxComponent0…, context: DebugContext} TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_CheckboxComponent0.detectChangesInternal (CheckboxComponent.ngfactory.js:293:44)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://ws1066.intern.orange-raidar.com:9002/main.bundle.js:68350:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://ws1066.intern.orange-raidar.com:9002/main.bundle.js:68455:44)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://ws1066.intern.orange-raidar.com:9002/main.bundle.js:68376:19)
    at DebugAppView._View_Table11.detectChangesInternal (Table.ngfactory.js:1300:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://ws1066.intern.orange-raidar.com:9002/main.bundle.js:68350:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://ws1066.intern.orange-raidar.com:9002/main.bundle.js:68455:44)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (http://ws1066.intern.orange-raidar.com:9002/main.bundle.js:68368:19)
    at DebugAppView._View_Table0.detectChangesInternal (Table.ngfactory.js:389:8)
```

My **CheckboxComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit ,
    Input,
    Output,
    EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

import { CheckboxEvent } from './checkbox.event';

import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';
var CHECKED_COLOR:string = 'rgba(68,138,255,0.87)';
var UNCHECKED_COLOR:string = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.54)';
var DISABLED_COLOR:string = 'grey';
@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox.component.css']
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() blockCheck:boolean = false;
    @Input() disabled:boolean = false;
    @Input() checked: boolean;
    @Output() checkedChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);
    @Output() check: EventEmitter<CheckboxEvent> = new EventEmitter<CheckboxEvent>(false);

    public checkedSVG:SafeHtml;
    public uncheckedSVG:SafeHtml;

    constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) {
        this.checkedSVG = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"/>
            </svg>`);
            // style="fill:` + CHECKED_COLOR + `"

        this.uncheckedSVG = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"/>
            </svg>`);
            //  style="fill:` + UNCHECKED_COLOR + `"
        this.checkbox = (this.checked)? this.checkbox = this.checkedSVG: this.uncheckedSVG;
    }

    public checkbox: SafeHtml;

    public onCheckboxClick(event:any) {
        if(this.disabled) {
            return;
        }
        var checked = !this.checked;
        this.checked = (this.blockCheck)? this.checked: !this.checked;
        this.check.emit(new CheckboxEvent(checked, event));
        if(checked === this.checked){
            this.setCheckbox();
        }
    }

    private setCheckbox() {
        this.checkbox = (this.checked)? this.checkbox = this.checkedSVG: this.uncheckedSVG;
        this.checkedChange.emit(this.checked);
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**checkbox component.html**

```
<div>
    <edit-dialog
        [(open)]="openEdit"
        [instance]="editInstance.instance"
        [dataFields]="editInstance.dataFields"
        (done)="doneEditing($event)"
        (cancel)="cancelEditing($event)">
        <span headline>Edit instance</span>
    </edit-dialog>

    <div class="container-fluid">
<!--Table head-->
        <div class="table-row header">
    <!-- index -->
            <div
                class="text index"
                *ngIf="showIndex && !selectColumns">
                No
            </div>
            <div class="text index clickable"
                *ngIf="selectColumns"
                (click)="showIndex = !showIndex"
                [ngStyle]="{'color': (showIndex)? activeColor: inactiveColor}">
                <div style="float: left; margin-right: 0.5em;">No</div>
                <div style="float: left;" >
                    <icon
                        *ngIf="showIndex"
                        icon="eye-open"
                        size="15"
                        [color]="activeColor" >
                    </icon>
                    <icon
                        *ngIf="!showIndex"
                        icon="eye-closed"
                        size="15"
                        [color]="inactiveColor" >
                    </icon>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!--visible columns-->
            <div
                *ngIf="!selectColumns"
                class="row-content">
                <div
                    *ngFor="let column of visibleColumns"
                    class="text clickable"
                    (click)="changeSorting(column)">
                    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 1em;">
                        {{ column.label }}
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <icon
                            *ngIf="sorting.column.label === column.label"
                            [icon]="(sorting.asc)? 'expand-arrow': 'expand-button'"
                            size="10">
                        </icon>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!--on selectColumns -->
            <div
                *ngIf="selectColumns"
                class="row-content">
                <div
                    class="text clickable"
                    *ngFor="let column of columns"
                    (click)="column.visible = !column.visible;
                        updateVisibleColumns()" >
                    <div
                        [ngStyle]="{'color': (column.visible)? activeColor: inactiveColor}"
                        style="float: left; margin-right: 1em;">
                        {{ column.label }}
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left;" >
                        <icon
                            *ngIf="column.visible"
                            icon="eye-open"
                            size="15"
                            [color]="activeColor" >
                        </icon>
                        <icon
                            *ngIf="!column.visible"
                            icon="eye-closed"
                            size="15"
                            [color]="inactiveColor" >
                        </icon>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!-- last columns for actions-->
            <div class="text icon" *ngIf="editable">
            </div>
            <div class="text index" *ngIf="selectable">
                <div>
                    <span
                        [title]="'selected/all' + ((selectMax > 0)? '/max. selectable' : '')">
                        {{ selected.size | delimit }}/{{ data.length | delimit}}{{(selectMax > 0)? '/'+selectMax: ''}}
                    </span>
                    <br>
                    <checkbox [checked]="allSelected" (checkedChange)="toggleSelectAll($event)"></checkbox>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

<!--Table body-->
        <div (mouseleave)="dragEnd()">
    <!-- EasterEgg-->
            <img src="./app/images/page-zero.gif" *ngIf="startAt < 0" style="width: 80%; height: 80%;" class="text"/>
    <!-- EasterEggEnd-->
    <!-- Table data-->
            <div *ngFor="
                let set of tableData
                | sort: ((sorting.asc)? 'asc': 'desc'): ['dataSet', sorting.column.value]
                | range: startAt: visibleEntries
                 let i = index;"
                 (mouseover)="mouseOver(set)"
                 (mouseup)="dragEnd()"
                 [class]="getEvenClass(i)"
                 (dblclick)="toggleWrap(tableData, set, $event)">
        <!-- Index -->
                <div class="text index" *ngIf="showIndex">
                    {{ i + 1 + startAt }}
                </div>
        <!-- Data according to columns-->
                <div
                    class="row-content" >
                    <div
                        [class]="'text ' + set.wrap"
                        *ngFor="let column of visibleColumns">
                        <a
                            *ngIf="column.isLink()"
                            [href]="set.dataSet.links[column.value]"
                            [innerHTML]="set.dataSet[column.value] | highlight:highlight | safeHTML">
                        </a>

                        <span *ngIf="column.isNumber()"
                            [innerHTML]="set.dataSet[column.value] |
                            delimit: 2: 'de'
                            | highlight:highlight | safeHTML">
                        </span>

                        <span *ngIf="column.isText()"
                        [innerHTML]="set.dataSet[column.value]
                        | highlight:highlight | safeHTML">
                        </span>

                        <span *ngIf="column.isDropdown()"
                        [innerHTML]="column.getValue(set.dataSet[column.value])
                        | highlight:highlight | safeHTML">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <!-- actions columns-->
                <div class="text icon icon-button" *ngIf="editable">
                    <icon
                        icon="create-new-pencil-button"
                        size="20"
                        color="black"
                        (click)="edit(set.dataSet)">
                    </icon>
                </div>
                <div class="text index" *ngIf="selectable">
                    <checkbox
                        [checked]="set.selected"
                        (check)="selectedDataSet(set, $event)"
                        [blockCheck]="true"
                        (mousedown)="dragStart(set)"
                        [disabled]="(!set.selected && maxSelected)"
                        onmousedown="if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()">
                    </checkbox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no clue how can i debug problems like these.

Edit instance is null but i am not able to understand why.
I am getting this exception in console logs. I have tried to search about handled promise rejection but unfortunately no luck.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot read property instance of undefined.

This means that editInstance is undefined and undefined does not have an instance property.

editInstance.instance